# Find probability of two randomly picked integers (from n integers) to be relatively prime

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

I came across this problem of finding said probability and my first attempt was to come up with following algorithm: I am counting number of pairs which are relatively prime.

```
int rel = 0
int total = n * (n - 1) / 2
for i in [1, n)
    for j in [i+1, n)
        if gcd(i, j) == 1
            ++rel;
return rel / total
```

which is *O(n^2)*.

Here is my attempt to reducing complexity:

**Observation (1):** 1 is relatively prime to `[2, n]` so `n - 1` pairs are trivial.

**Observation (2):** 2 is not relatively prime to even numbers in the range `[4, n]` so remaining odd numbers are relatively prime to 2, so

```
 #Relatively prime pairs = (n / 2) if n is even 

                         = (n / 2 - 1) if n is odd.
```

So my improved algorithm would be:

```
int total = n * (n - 1) / 2
int rel = 0
if (n % 2) // n is odd
    rel = (n - 1) + n / 2 - 1
else // n is even
    rel = (n - 1) + n / 2

for i in [3, n)
    for j in [i+1, n)
        if gcd(i, j) == 1
            ++rel;
return rel / total
```

With this approach I could reduce two loops, but worst case time complexity is still `O(n^2)`.

**Question:** My question is can we exploit any mathematical properties other than above to find the desired probability in linear time?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the distribustion of your n integers? Are these uniformly distributed random integers, or something else? Maybe asking your question on http://math.stackexchange.com/ would be more fruitful.

Comment: My input would be: for n = 10, array: [1...n] or [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to calculate the [Euler's Totient Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) for all integers from **1** to **n**. Euler's totient or phi function, φ(n), is a arithmetical function that counts the number of positive integers less than or equal to n that are relatively prime to n.

To calculate the function efficiently, you can use a modified version of [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Here is a sample C++ code -

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXN 10000000

int phi[MAXN+1];
bool isPrime[MAXN+1];

void calculate_phi() {
    int i,j;
    for(i = 1; i <= MAXN; i++) {
        phi[i] = i;
        isPrime[i] = true;
    }

    for(i = 2; i <= MAXN; i++) if(isPrime[i]) {
        for(j = i+i; j <= MAXN; j+=i) {
            isPrime[j] = false;
            phi[j] = (phi[j] / i) * (i-1);
        }
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= MAXN; i++) {
        if(phi[i] == i) phi[i]--;
    }
}

int main() {
    calculate_phi();
    return 0;
}
```

It uses the Euler's Product Formula described on the Wikipedia page of Totient Function.

Calculating the complexity of this algorithm is a bit tricky, but it is much less than `O(n^2)`. You can get results for `n = 10^7` pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3):

The number of integers in the range 0 .. n that are coprime to n is the Euler totient function of n. You are computing the sum of such values, e.g. called summatory totient function. Methods to compute this sum fast are for example
described [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientSummatoryFunction.html). You should easily get a method with a better than quadratic complexity,
depending on how fast you implement the totient function.

Even better are the references listed in the encyclopedia of integer sequences: http://oeis.org/A002088, though many of the references require some math skills.

Using these formulas you can even get an implementation that is sublinear.

Answer (score 3):

For each prime *p*, probability of it dividing a randomly picked number between 1 and *n* is

[*n* / *p*] / *n*

([*x*] being the biggest integer not greater than *x*). If *n* is large, this is approximately 1/*p*.

The probability of it dividing *two* such randomly picked numbers is

([*n* / *p*] / *n*)<sup>2</sup>

Again, this is 1/*p*<sup>2</sup> for large *n*.

Two numbers are coprime if no prime divides both, so the probability in question is the product

Π<sub>*p* is prime</sub>(1 - ([*n* / *p*] / *n*)<sup>2</sup>)

It is enough to calculate it for all primes less than or equal to *n*. As *n* goes to infinity, this product approaches 6/*π*<sup>2</sup>.

I'm not sure you can use the totient function directly, as described in the other answers.

Comment: the proof that the answer is $6/pi^{2}$ can be followed at multiple places online, for example, a short and clear one is this: https://youtu.be/_zwbqL-dAZ4